# @Url.Action("action","controller") not working in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.GroupTypeNames.Count; i++)
            {
                <nav id="options" class="work-nav">
                    <ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">                         
                        <li>
                            @{
                var item = Model.GroupTypeNames[i];
                var selected = i == 0 ? " class=\"selected\"" : "";
                            }

                    <a onclick='window.location.href('@Url.Action("GetData", "Groups", new { id = @item.Id })')' data-option-value="*"@Html.Raw(selected)>@item.TypeName</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            }
```

I tried with this way to
`@Html.ActionLink(@item.TypeName, "GetData", "Groups", new { id=@item.Id }, null)`

controller code

```
 public ActionResult GetData(Guid id)
        {
// code
```

not getting called `GetData` why is it ? no errors to after debugging :/

Comment: Your javascript is bad. You are using `'` single quotes for your attribute value of onclick as well as your string inside your javascript. Switch one of the pairs to double quotes `"'.

Comment: Your action is named GetDatabyId but you're using "GetData" as action name

Comment: Please include the html produced by the actions, why they aren't correct, and what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a  title="Name"  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GetData", "Groups", 
new { id = @item.Id })'" > @item.TypeName</a>
```

i think this work well for you.

Comment: thanks unable to set `data-option-value` as `selected` when I click on <a>

Answer (score 0):

You are using the quotes incorrectly while building the link. Use a separate variable to build the link and then use it to render the HTML.

```
@{
   var item = Model.GroupTypeNames[i];
   var selected = i == 0 ? " class=\"selected\"" : "";
   var url = @Url.Action("GetDataById", "Groups", new {id = @item.Id});
}
<a onclick='window.location.href("@url")' 
   data-option-value="*" 
   @Html.Raw(selected)>@item.TypeName</a>
```

Instead of the onclick function you can also directly use the href attribute

```
<a href="@url" data-option-value="*" @Html.Raw(selected)>@item.TypeName</a>
```